# Autofocus scroll box

Tags: html, autofocus

Autofocus is used on forms and buttons. What I need is a scroll box to be auto selected. Note that this is not an text area. 
The code I have for the scroll box is:

```
<div style="height:120px;width:120px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;">

As you can see, once there's enough text in this box, the box will grow scroll bars... that's why we call it a scroll box! You could also place an image into the scroll box.

</div>
```

I need this scroll box to be auto selected because I'm making a project where my website is controllable through external buttons. The up arrow and down arrow are used to read an informative text. Of course the element has to be selected first in order for it to work.

Comment: can you show your effort?

Comment: If by effort you mean code (sorry english is not my native language) . This is the code I used:                    <div style="height:120px;width:120px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;">
As you can see, once there's enough text in this box, the box will grow scroll bars... that's why we call it a scroll box! You could also place an image into the scroll box.
</div>

Comment: Never post code as comment. add it in your question by edit.

Comment: sorry it's the first question I posted on this site, I edited my question so now the code is visible.